# Are hi fi amplifiers used in music production?

Tags: production

1. Are hi fi amplifiers used in music production?
2. What if I run the signal through the hi fi amplifier and record the output? It has to become wider, more volume, deeper ? Does that make sense ?

Comment: The Blue Nile issued recordings on Linn Records, and there's an anecdote in the book Nileism about how they blew up some Linn Isobarik (very high end hifi) speakers that they were trying out as studio monitors. You wonder how loud they had to crank them to get them to blow up.,,

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - those Blue Nile recordings are still used in sound engineering schools in the "**this** is how you do it" sections. They are phenomenal recordings; with a very odd phenomenon - it doesn't matter how loud you play them back, you can still talk over them in a normal voice & be perfectly intelligible. I'm not surprised they overloaded speakers trying to get it to sound "loud".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they used?
Undoubtedly someone, somewhere has tried it & swears by it.

Will it make things wider, louder, deeper?
Not if it is **actually** HiFi.
HiFi, by definition, is designed to add as little colouration to the signal as possible.

Could you 'torture' HiFi into adding 'interest' by pushing it hard into a variety of speakers?
Sure, if you can afford it.

Would I bother?
No.

There are a myriad amp simulators available in software, with profiles from "so subtle you can't tell it's on" to "Marshall on 11". I'd just use one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to test your production on a Hifi amp and speakers.

You may have heard of the loudness wars where increasing levels of compression are applied to help the music punch through. E.g. to play a song on a portable radio on a building site or  in a noisy environment. Going too far can make the production sound awful on good HiFi. So producers check their work on a variety of devices before they release the song.